# MySQL ODBC + setting up a DSN on windows + MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Sorry for the vague title, but here's my problem.

I connect to my database in MySQL Workbench using the following method : TCP/IP over SSH

However, when I try to set up the DSN on Windows 7 via:

```
Control Panel -> Administrative Tools ->Data Sources (ODBC)
```

It won't connect. My other databases that connect in MySQL Workbench using Standard TCP/IP are able to connect when I set up the DSN on Windows, but I think the SSH is throwing it off.

Could someone please let me know if it's possible to set up a DSN on windows using a connection that uses SSH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this question in the future, I just figured out that you need an SSH client like [putty](http://putty.org) to do this.

Comment: Can you tell me how to acheive that with putty??